# How to properly link to GLEW for a .dll project?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, glew

I am creating a plugin (.dll) for another application in C++, which relies on OpenGL/GLEW. I have linked my project against `glew32.lib`, and have placed `glew32.dll` in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. Everything compiles well, the application recognizes the plugin, but it crashes whenever a gl-function is called (e.g. glCreateShader) because they are all NULL.

I have created a GL context, and afterwards initialized GLEW (with `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE`) and it returns GLEW_OK. However, still all gl-functions are NULL. Similar questions suggest to use flags like `GLEW_STATIC` and `GLEW_BUILD` flags, but no combination seems to work.

The code is as follows (where `Log` is just some logging function):

```cpp
// Set context
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);

// Check if context is null (which is not the case)
if (wglGetCurrentContext() == NULL)
    Log("current context is null");

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err != GLEW_OK)
    FatalAppExit(NULL, TEXT("Failed to initialize GLEW!"));

Log("glewInit returns " + std::to_string(err)); // Indeed, glewInit returns GLEW_OK == GLEW_NO_ERRORS == 0

// Check some function addresses whether they are null (they all are!)
if (glCreateShader == NULL)
    Log("glCreateShader is NULL");
if (glCreateProgram == NULL)
    Log("glCreateProgram is NULL");
if (glAttachShader == NULL)
    Log("glAttachShader is NULL");
```

The same code does work when I compile my project to be an .exe (that is, all functions then do have valid addresses after `glewInit()`), so it seems something has to change in order to use GLEW from within a .dll. Does anyone know what to change?

Comment: In wiggle you have to create a context to determine what OpenGL capabilities your system has. Once you have a context and have initialized GLEW you can query to capabilities and instantiate a proper context and reinitialize GLEW.

Comment: @vandench To my knowledge, creating a context with `wglCreateContext` creates a version 2.1 context (which would be fine by me), and a context with attributes can be created using `wglCreateContextAttribsARB`. However, after creating the (dummy) context + calling glewInit(), the expression `wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context")` returns false so I can't make a context this way.. However, for the .exe it returns true, and it is possible. There really seems to be a difference between .exe's and .dll's ?